# Is it possible to add http headers. for example set-cookie, via ampscript or ssjs in ExactTarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, httpresponse

I would prefer not to use javascript to set a cookie if possible. I am pretty sure it's possible to read a cookie using HTTPRequestHeader(S1), but I'd like to be able to set one when a user submits a form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SSJS. There's a SetValue and GetValue function for the HTTPHeader:

- [**Server-Side JavaScript Functions**](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/utilities_server_side_javascript_functions/)

Comment: Any suggestions on how to set a cookie using SSJS? Reference [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126416/how-to-set-a-cookie-using-ssjs)

Answer (score 1):

David's correct. You can do it by setting the HTTP Header, but there's a more intuitive function out there. To set a cookie with SSJS:

```
Platform.Response.SetCookie("MyCookie", "MyCookieValue");
```

The SetCookie function has a few overloaded variants:

```
SetCookie(string name, string value)
SetCookie(string name, string value, DateTime expirationDate)
SetCookie(string name, string value, bool secureOnly)
SetCookie(string name, string value, DateTime expirationDate, bool secureOnly)
```