# How to set a cookie using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, microsites

This question relates to: [Is it possible to add http headers. for example set-cookie, via ampscript or ssjs in ExactTarget?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/52011/is-it-possible-to-add-http-headers-for-example-set-cookie-via-ampscript-or-ssj)

The answer on that question does not specifically call out how to set a cookie with SSJS, it just references the HTTPHeader.SetValue() function.

I've tried the following to set the cookie and have been unsuccessful.

```
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Set-Cookie","foo=bar");
HTTPHeader.SetValue("Cookie","foo=bar");
```

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you searched for and tried the standard methods of setting a cookie? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie

Comment: The link you provided shows the following example to set a session cookie (which is what I'm trying to do):
`Set-Cookie: theme=light` I'm still missing how I'm doing it wrong in the context of SSJS. Can you enlighten me and provide example code that should work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `SetCookie` value you can use in SSJS.

```
<script runat=server>
 Platform.Response.SetCookie("cookieName","cookieValue","2015-12-31 140000.999",true);
```

Properties are below. Values 3 and 4 (the date and time and HTTPS connection) are optional.

```
SetCookie(Session cookie name, Session cookie value, Date and time value indicating cookie expiration, Indicates whether cookie works with only HTTPS connections)
```

Note that there is no way to set persistent cookies via this function and it only sets it as a session cookie (deletes the cookie after the browser is closed).

Comment: adding to Jackson's answer: the datetime string can be in this format: ``5/1/2019 12:12:06``. You can create that with the default ``getHours()``, ``getFullYear()``,... methods. SFMC will **auto-convert that to GMT** inside of the SetCookie() method! A working method to create the datetime string was provided by Adam here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/145821/28940

Comment: @jackson Chen I just tested this and it seems I was able to close my browser and come back and the cookie was still there. What am I missing?

Comment: In fact I cannot even seem to delete my cookie with RemoveCookie