# Date manipulation Function SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

I want to delete the records from Data Extension based on Date Field in my DE i.e. I want to delete record which were created date before 30 days.But I didn't find date manipulation function in SSJS like dateadd() in ampscript

Answer (score 7):

You can do date math like you would in regular JS.  I typically use a simple function to format the date:

```
<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("core", "1");

var today = new Date();
var prevDate = new Date();
prevDate.setDate(today.getDate()-30);
Write("<br>today: " + today);
Write("<br>prevDate: " + prevDate);
Write("<br>formatted prevDate: " + getTimestamp(prevDate));


function getTimestamp(dt) {

  var h = dt.getHours();
  var m = dt.getMinutes();
  var s = dt.getSeconds();
  if(h<10) h = '0'+h;
  if(m<10) m = '0'+m;
  if(s<10) s = '0'+s;

  var ts = (dt.getMonth()+1) + '/' + dt.getDate() + '/' + dt.getFullYear() + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ":" + s;

  return ts;
}


</script>
```

**Output**

```
today: Tue, 25 Oct 2016 07:35:44 GMT-06:00
prevDate: Sun, 25 Sep 2016 07:35:44 GMT-06:00
formatted prevDate: 9/25/2016 07:35:44
```

Comment: thanks just 1 more question... where will the output of write() come? on Microsite

Comment: It's just for output from within the script block.  It'll show wherever it's executed.

Comment: when i paste above code in interaction>script and then run that script where will the output come?

Comment: Script activities don't have output, but you can write to a data extension for logging.