# Store the unknown customers information in SFMC DE who visit the landing page through Cookies

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, cookies

We have a requirement where need to store the information for unknown users who visit our SFMC landing page.Is it possible to identify the information through cookies or collect tracking code in SFMC and if yes so how can store into SFMC DE.

Comment: Would that be any page or a landing page hosted as a Cloud Page from Marketing Cloud?

Comment: It would be SFMC CloudPage.

Comment: What information do you want to store exactly?

Comment: Visit date, browser information and any single unique information through will be able to identify if the same user visit the page again.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a `SetCookie` function that you can [set using SSJS to store cookie values](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126416/how-to-set-a-cookie-using-ssjs).

You can also use the `UpsertData` function to [write records to the data extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/upsertdata.htm).

Note that you’ll need to uniquely identify these records in your data extension so using the `GUID` function might help. Since the visitors will be unidentified, the [GUID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/GUID.htm) will help to assign a random unique value to each record.

Comment: ,Thank you for your answer. As I am not much familiar with SSJS so have further doubt that How will be able to fetch that SetCookie data or to upsert into DE. My goal is to store the cookie history into DE and verify the entry every time when a user try to access the landing page. Thank you in advance for you assistance.